# How to implement standford POS tagger from google colaboratory?

Tags: python, nlp, google-colaboratory

The following code I want to implement from google colab using python to work with Stanford POStagger. The path for jar, model, java path doesn't work. I have connected them from google drive to colab and the path is correct. But when I compile it, it generates the error! I am a beginner in this field. Help me out how to compile this code from google colab.

```
"PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-f2ef4341550a> in <module>()
      9 tagger.java_options='-mx4096m'          ### Setting higher memory limit for long sentences
     10 sentence = 'This is testing'
---> 11 print (tagger.tag(sentence.split()))

4 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, start_new_session)
   1549                         if errno_num == errno.ENOENT:
   1550                             err_msg += ': ' + repr(err_filename)
-> 1551                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1552                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
   1553 

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/content/drive/MyDrive/Research/java.exe'"
```

```
    import os
    java_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Research/java.exe"
    os.environ['JAVAHOME'] = java_path

    from nltk.tag.stanford import StanfordPOSTagger
    path_to_model = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Research/english- 
    bidirectional-distsim.tagger"
    path_to_jar = jar = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Research/stanford- 
    postagger.jar"
    tagger=StanfordPOSTagger(path_to_model, path_to_jar)
    tagger.java_options='-mx4096m'          ### Setting higher memory 
    limit for long sentences
    sentence = 'This is testing'
    print (tagger.tag(sentence.split()))
```

Comment: error shows that you don't `Permission` to use `java.exe`. Maybe first move all to local disk to test it.

Comment: yes. But is there any other way to link up java.exe from google colab? I connected it from drive. May be this isn't the actual approach. I couldn't find any article about it. I only found many people implement it from jupyter not google colab! But I have to implement it from google colab. My pc ram is not sufficient to work with other necessary files of my research.

Comment: maybe first test simple solution to see if it can work on your computer. And you have to know that it will run all code on your local computer, not on Google Colab. You would have to loging to Google server (using SSH) and start code on server to run it on server)

Comment: BTW: as I know `Google Colab` uses servers with Linux/Unix` but you try to run `.exe` program which is for `Windows`

Comment: if you want to use `Java` on `Google Colab` then you should use version which is already installed on server - `!java --version` - it will not work with version for `Windows`. If you need full path to Java on server then check `!which java`. I see `/usr/bin/java`

Comment: java_path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/Research/java.exe" instead of this which command i have to use? i am very beginner in this field that's why i couldn't get your point. Thank you.

Comment: java_path = "/usr/bin/java"  when i use this again shows the same error

Comment: first you should check if you have Java in your Google Colab and what path it has. `!which java` - and later copy this path to `java_path`. And it can't get the same error if you use different value in `java_path` - it should have different path in error message.